# Removing vowels from a list of strings

Tags: python, list, element

I have a list(lets call it "list") of 5 elements:

```
['sympathize.', 'sufficient.', 'delightful.', 'contrasted.', 'unsatiable']
```

I would like to **remove** **vowels**    ( `vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')`) from **every item** of the list and and the final result should be this

**The list without vowels:**

```
['sympthz.', 'sffcnt.', 'dlghtfl.', 'cntrstd.', 'nstbl']
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
list = ['sympathize.', 'sufficient.', 'delightful.', 'contrasted.','unsatiable']
     vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
        for x in list.lower():
            if x in vowels:
                words = list.replace(x,"")
```

Output :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: well, list has no attribute lower, you can call x.lower()

Comment: Don't use the name `list`, as it is a builtin type in Python.

Comment: words = ['sympathize.', 'sufficient.', 'delightful.', 'contrasted.','unsatiable']
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
for x in words.lower():
    if x in vowels:
        words = words.replace(x,"")

Comment: I am getting the same error (  for x in words.lower():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
mylist = ['sympathize.', 'sufficient.', 'delightful.', 'contrasted.','unsatiable']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    for v in vowels:
        mylist[i] = mylist[i].replace(v,"")
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
l = ['sympathize.', 'sufficient.', 'delightful.', 'contrasted.', 'unsatiable']

table = str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiou')

[s.translate(table) for s in l]
# ['sympthz.', 'sffcnt.', 'dlghtfl.', 'cntrstd.', 'nstbl']
```

Comment: That's also a great way, thanks for the add!